# How to load a high vertices and high polygons object using SceneKit?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I start to build a 3D scene using SceneKit, I have converted a .obj file into .scn file, and I drag a camera, but I couldn't see anything, only the whole white color. Then I found that the object I have converted have high polygons and vertices, almost 21000 vertices and 7220 polygons. I think this is the problem. So what can I do? Is it possible to display those object with high vertices and polygons?

---

**Twice Edit**

I have solved this 'problem', simply give the zFar property a higher value.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, but I don't think there's a specific limit to the polygon count.  Generally, a high polygon count would just mean a slow frame rate.  When you say, "you couldn't see anything," do you mean in your app?  In Xcode?  What software are you using to create the scene? Are you exporting it from something like Maya?  Sounds like you might just have the camera pointed in the wrong direction...

Comment: actually, I place the camera in the right place. I think the object is too big. I have solve my problem. Just give the zFar property a high value. thank you